# Is there a way to make a page not follow any layout

Tags: blazor

All my pages are following MainLayout by default.

Is it possible to tell a page to not follow any layout or would I have to make a new layout that is just empty and tell it to follow that?

Nothing showed up on the interweb and making an empty layout seems messy.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no way to tell Blazor not to follow a layout, at least not one that requires only changing some settings. It may be possible to implement this in code, but this is going to be unworthy enterprise... The easiest and most appropriate way to do that is to create a custom layout like this:

### MyCustomLayout.razor

```
@inherits LayoutComponentBase

<div class="main">

    <div class="content px-4">
        @Body
    </div>
</div>
```

And use it like this:

```
@page "/counter"
@layout Component
```

This will result in rendering the Counter component within your layout component. You may need some CSS styling...

Hope this helps...

Comment: Is any way to limit / avoid loading of scripts from Layout https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76109718/prevent-loading-css-and-js-files-within-blazor-server-side-application-with-diff