# Prevent loading css and JS files within Blazor Server side Application with different Layouts

Tags: c#, blazor, blazor-server-side

I am working on a  blazor server side project which is using 2 different layouts . The way the project is organised is like below

```
_Layout 

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
   ref to all css files
</head>
<body>
    @RenderBody()
    <scripts>
      ref to all js files 
    </scripts>
</body>
```

And then

```
_MainLayOut
 
   @Body
```

And then

```
_EmptyLayout
 
    <style type="text/css">
      define my custom styles for this layout But I dont want to load any of the  css & js files with this layout  
    </style>
     @Body
```

And the application is using MainLayout as the default one under App.razor

```
   <RouteView RouteData="@routeData" DefaultLayout="@typeof(MainLayout)" />
```

Example of a custom  EmptyLayoutPage is like below

```
@page "/customlayout_simple"
@layout EmptyLayout
@inject NavigationManager navManager
<div>My page contents</div>
```

When the EmptyLayoutPage is loading while inspecting I can see that all the css and scripts associated with _Layout is loading
and conflicting with my EmptyLayout styles

I tried to place the scripts from _Layout to MainLayout then i was getting error
Script tags should not be placed inside components because they cannot be updated dynamically. To fix this, move the script tag to the 'index. html' file or another static location

So how can i ensure that when an  EmptyLaout page is loaded the css and js associated with _Layout is not loading
Or how can i specify the js and css which is at presetn inside Layout just for MainLayout

Answer (score 0):

If you want to have different css for different layouts you have to either make conditional css referencing or you isolate the css in a Mainlayout.razor.css and use it from there.

Comment: How about preventing JS scripts to be loaded?

Comment: Inside your _Layout.cshtml you can define if-statements following this syntax: @if(<condition>){ <code> }. I would look into css isolation for the conflicting styles maybe you will find an answer there. Here you have a link: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/components/css-isolation?view=aspnetcore-7.0